# On form button click success, form validations fire again

Tags: vue.js, meteor, vuelidate

Hopefully this is a newbie question.
I am using Vuelidate to validate my form and the form validations works fine, when the “send email” button is clicked.However on success, instead of showing me the successful message, the system shows that all the form controls have errors(This is because I have bound the name, email, message controls to their corresponding empty data elements).
What am I missing?
How can I fix this issue?

**Contact.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div>
    <section class="slice slice-lg" id="sct_contact_form">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="mb-5 text-center">
              <span class="badge badge-soft-info badge-pill badge-lg">
                Contact
              </span>
              <h3 class=" mt-4">Send us a message</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <form>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-control-label">Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name" v-model="user.name" id="name" name="name" :class="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && $v.user.name.$error }" >
                        <div v-if="submitted && !$v.user.name.required" class="invalid-feedback">Name is required</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>                
                  </div>
                  <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-control-label">Email</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="email@example.com" 
                        v-model="user.email" id="email" name="email" :class="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && $v.user.email.$error }" >
                         <div v-if="submitted && $v.user.email.$error" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <span v-if="!$v.user.email.required">Email is required</span>
                            <span v-if="!$v.user.email.email">Email is invalid</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-control-label">Message</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" data-toggle="autosize" placeholder="Tell us a few words ..." rows="3" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 96.9922px;" 
                        v-model="user.message" id="message" name="message" :class="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && $v.user.message.$error }" ></textarea>
                        <div v-if="submitted && $v.user.message.$error" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <span v-if="!$v.user.message.required">Message is required</span>
                            <span v-if="!$v.user.message.minLength">Message must be at least 6 characters</span>
                        </div>  
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center mt-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark rounded-pill" v-on:click="SendEmail()">Send your message</button>                
                    <span class="d-block mt-4 text-sm">We'll get back to you in 24-48 h.</span>
                    <div v-if="submitted" class="valid-feedback">
                        <span v-if="!$v.user.name.$error && !$v.user.email.$error && !$v.user.message.$error">Your email was send successfully. We'll get back to you in 24-48 h.</span>                    
                    </div>
                  </div>              
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </template>
```

```js
import { Email } from '../api/email.js';
import { required, email, minLength, sameAs } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

export default {
  name: "Contact",
  components:{
  },
  data() {
      return {
          user: {
              name: "",
              email: "",
              message: ""
          },
          submitted: false
      };
  },
  validations: {
      user: {
          name: { required },
          email: { required, email },
          message: { required, minLength: minLength(6) }
      }
  },
  methods: {
    SendEmail() {
      this.submitted = true;
      this.$v.$touch();
      if (this.$v.$invalid) {
          return;
      }

      var nameWithEmailText="Email message from: "+ this.user.name + "\nEmail message: " + this.user.message;
      var subject="Email from contact us page in common membership website";
      Meteor.call('email.send', this.user.email, subject, nameWithEmailText); 
      this.user.name='';
      this.user.email='';
      this.user.message=''; 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait for the `Meteor.call()` to complete, then [reset the validation state](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/#sub-v-methods).

For example

```js
Meteor.call('email.send', this.user.email, subject, nameWithEmailText, (error, result) => {
  this.user.name = ''
  this.user.email = ''
  this.user.message = ''

  this.$v.$reset()
})
```